# For a given wikipedia article, find all wikipedia articles containing hyperlink to the input article in the text

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Let me try to explain my problem: For a Wikipedia article url, Let's say Yann LeCun (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yann_LeCun), I would like to retrieve URLs of wikipedia articles that contains a word with this hyperlink. In this case, for example, one of the returned URLS can be the URL of the  Meta AI article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_AI) because inside that article there is this text:

*"FAIR was directed by New York University's [Yann LeCun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yann_LeCun), a deep learning Professor and Turing Award winner."*

Is there any kind of API or python code to do something like that? I've seen "What links here" tool available in wikipedia but unfortunately not all the articles in its output list has text with hyperlinks to the input article. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give an example of a page from the "What links here" tool that doesn't have the hyperlink?

Comment: @MichaelCao Sure, here is the outptu of "What Links here" for Yann_LeCun: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Yann_LeCun . If you look at the first article in the list, which is artificial intelligence ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence ) you'll see that that article does not mention Yann_LeCun at all. Is it clearer now?

Comment: On that article, you can find a link in the expandable tables "Articles related to Artificial intelligence" -> "Differentiable computing" -> "People"

Is this acceptable, or do you want it specifically in the body of the article?

Comment: @MichaelCao Thanks for your reply! I want to have only the articles that have the link in the body of the article. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but if I were to attempt this. I would start by looking at all the articles listed by WhatLinksHere and then use a webscraping package like BeautifulSoup to look for the hyperlink limited within what you would define as the body of the article.

Comment: Yea, that's also what I have in mind..

Answer (score -1):

You can use this query to get all the wikilinks in an article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=Yann_LeCun&pllimit=500&plnamespace=0

You can then iterate through that list and query the same endpoint with a different title and check whether your original article is present in that. You can even use the pllimit parameter to limit what's returned e.g:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=Meta_AI&pllimit=500&plnamespace=0&pltitles=Yann_LeCun

Returns:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "normalized": [
            {
                "from": "Meta_AI",
                "to": "Meta AI"
            }
        ],
        "pages": {
            "70734095": {
                "pageid": 70734095,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Meta AI",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "ns": 0,
                        "title": "Yann LeCun"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the length of the links list is 1, then there you have a positive match.